# Responsive dropdown menu with smaller screen sizes

Tags: menus, responsive

Working on a theme template and trying to make the menu responsive, so that it will change from a horizontal layout into a block format at a certain screen resolution.  I have tried one tutorial which I couldn't get to work, lack of experience on my behalf but also a little unsure how to implement in to WordPress as the menu is generated dynamically, and the tutorial was based on a fixed HTML structure menu.  Now attempting a second but hitting a wall at the moment, hence my question.

The tutorial I am following is located below, the author has been helpful but I don't want to push his patience.  I have some comments on his blog, which explains a little but will reiterate all below.

http://www.justinwhall.com/responsive-drop-down-menu-with-css-media-queries-jquery/#comment-8391

I have copied his Java script into a file called mobile-menu.js then registered and enqueued this in the correct way within functions.php

I am using a test website http://www.simples.net23.net

The CSS I am using is as follows:

```
/*=========== helper classes =====================*/
p.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  font-size: 1.4em !important; }
p.mobile-nav span {
  font-size: 1.3em; }
.mobile li {
  display: block;
  width: 43%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
@media only screen
and (max-width : 768px) {
  p.mobile-nav {
  display: block; }
}
```

I haven't placed all the Java code here as it's about 30 lines, and is possibly better read on his blog.

Below is some of the code from my `header.php` file, regarding the menu:

```
<header id="header_container" class="group">

<div id="nav">      
<nav class="main-menu">
Menu <span>+</span>
<?php   /* Adding the menu called 'main' to the header, within HTML5 tag */
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main' ) );
?>
</nav>
</div>

</header>
```

I think my issue lies with my HTML and CSS, and using the correct selectors so the Java script can work it's magic.  I have looked at the generated menu with Firebug, but as it's generated by WordPress having a bit of an issue understanding the structure, and then the correct selectors to use.

Cheers,

Ant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at that tutorial, you need to match up the jQuery selector with the menu markup. You can see in this line

```
navigation: $('#nav ul'),
```

that the jQuery expects your menu to be in a `<ul>` inside a parent element with the id `nav`. Luckily, that's really easy to do. Just change your `wp_nav_menu()` arguments to:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main', 'container_id'=>'nav' ) );
```

`wp_nav_menu()` can do a lot more than that, so you might want to go through the available arguments just for future knowledge.

Also, it seems worth mentioning that the new official WordPress theme [Twenty Twelve](https://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentytwelve) uses a responsive menu solution that you might want to take a look at.

Comment: mrwweb this sounds exactly what I am looking for,I will have a look at this later today and get back, cheers for the quick response.  Cheers for the tip on the Twenty Twelve theme as well.

Comment: mrwweb, I ended up opting for the twentyywelve way and have isolated all the components. So thanks for the tip.